# Login Using KeyCloak Token in Angular

Tags: angular, curl, keycloak

I have got Keycloak access token using CURL command in Command Prompt and written that token in text file in local drive. I want my angular app to read that token and login automatically using that token. Is it possible? And if yes, how?

Comment: Rather than using CURL, you could use the built-in [`httpClient`](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient) to retreive your token and use it throughout your app.

Comment: Ok. But problem is same; how would I use that token in angular app to log in? Please note that this token has been taken without using angular app.

Comment: I suppose you need this library to make things easy for yourself (: https://github.com/mauriciovigolo/keycloak-angular#readme

Comment: Well, it depends on your application flow. Normally, you would use it like any other JWT token. But it really depends on your infrastructure and your code. It's really hard to answer your correctly here.

Answer (score 0):

Only if the user picks the file or drops it into your control which can read that file. 
Overwise it would have been a security breach.